Why is GitLab CI jobs not running with "rules: changes"?
My goal
is to only run the jobs in build and deploy under 2 conditions (on branch main):

a JSON file exists in the src folder
there is a change to a JSON file in the src folder

Implementation

I tried utilizing before_script, find, wc to check for condition 1.
I tried using rules: changes to check for condition 2.
V&V

Pipeline editor passes the GitLab CI Lint and validation check
if condition in before_script behaves as expected when put under script
I have tested with commits that should trigger the rules and skip the before_script conditions (i.e. adding, editing, removing JSONs in src/, commiting non JSON changes, all on the correct main branch)



Problem

None of the jobs are triggered nor run


More detail and code

The first condition targets situations where

a new branch is made and no JSON files exist, or
commit removes all JSON files in src

The second condition targets situations where

commits do not have any updates to the JSON files in the src folder


My pipeline visualization looks like
docker-build (build) ---- process-build (build)
                     \___ app-deploy (deploy)

*job (stage)

.gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

docker-build:
  stage: build
  before_script: 'if [ $(find ./src -name "*.json" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then exit 0; fi'
  script:
    - docker build
    ...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      changes:
        - ./src/**/*.json

process-build:
  stage: build
  needs: docker-build
  script:
    ...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      changes:
        - ./src/**/*.json

app-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  needs: docker-build
  script:
    ...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      changes:
        - ./src/**/*.json



GitLab's CI/CD rules uses the ruby function fnmatch(pattern, path) which matching directories or files recursively with the wildcard **.

Additional details:
Glob patterns are interpreted with Ruby’s
File.fnmatch with the flags File::FNM_PATHNAME | File::FNM_DOTMATCH | File::FNM_EXTGLOB.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#ruleschanges
The flag File::FNM_DOTMATCH is already being added which doubles the dot symbol in your example.

File::FNM_DOTMATCH
Flag File::FNM_DOTMATCH makes the '*' pattern
match a filename starting with '.'.

You should use /src/**/*.json instead of ./src/**/*.json.
